# how to add a file to mvc 4 project using c# dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Actually in CSharp WindowsFormApplication I could able to add `.cs` file to the project dynamically using Additem to the project.see the below Example that I used to add in `CSharp WindowsFormApplication`.
Ex:

```
p.AddItem("Compile", fileNames);
p.Save();
```

Now i want to add files to the MVC 4 project same as in `CSharp WindowsFormApplication` but the problem is in `MVC` we have different folder structure(i.e., Controller, Model, View) and my doubt is how to add the files to the particular location.

Comment: Just curious, are these .cs files supposed to be used by the application itself?  If you were able to add them dynamically, wouldn't the project then have to recompile itself in order for these files to actually work?

Comment: No, I am generating the .cs files in one application and adding them to another application.